# Issue with sorting one column after rank is assigned

Tags: r

*****This is to deal with the question asked in Coursera and hence I may not be able to reveal the complete code*****

hi,
below is my data frame (outcome_H)

```
Hospital_Name   H_A H_F PN
ABC             4.5  5  6
CDE             4.5  1  3
EFG             5    2  1
```

1) I need to rank the column provided in the function call (it could be one of H_A ,H_F,PN)

2) there will also a rank be provided in the call. Need to match that rank with the rank calculated above and return the respective Hospital_Name

I had used ties.method="first" to solve the tie problem. But however when I look at the final output the hospital name is not sorted. 
Example: if i give rank =2, I expect CDE to be printed, but due to some problems(which I am note aware) ABC gets printed for rank=2 and CDE is printed for rank=1.

Below are some parts of code for better understanding:

```
H_A <- as.numeric(outcome_H$H_A)
HA <- H_A[order(H_A)]       // newly added piece to order the value
df <- data.frame(HA,round(rank(HA,ties.method="first")),outcome_H$Hospital_Name)
rowss <- df[order(df$round.rank.HA..),]
```

Before ordering Output:

```
     HA round.rank.HA..          outcome_H.Hospital.Name
42  8.1               1       FORT DUNCAN MEDICAL CENTER
192 8.5               2  TOMBALL REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER
61  8.7               4           DETAR HOSPITAL NAVARRO
210 8.7               4 CYPRESS FAIRBANKS MEDICAL CENTER
69  8.8               6  MISSION REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER
117 8.8               6           METHODIST HOSPITAL,THE
```

After Ordering output:

```
  HA round.rank.HA..ties.method....first...                       outcome_H.Hospital.Name
1 8.1                                      1                  PROVIDENCE MEMORIAL HOSPITAL
2 8.5                                      2      MEMORIAL HERMANN BAPTIST ORANGE HOSPITAL
3 8.7                                      3              PETERSON REGIONAL MEDICAL CENTER
4 8.7                                      4 CHILDREN'S HOSPITAL -SCOTT & WHITE HEALTHCARE
5 8.8                                      5            UNITED REGIONAL HEALTH CARE SYSTEM
6 8.8                                      6              ST JOSEPH REGIONAL HEALTH CENTER
```

As you can see, the data with hospital names are completely incorrect.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Thanks,
Pravellika J

Answer (score 0):

You could try `H_A <- as.numeric(as.character(outcome_H$H_A))`

Output

```
HA round.rank.HA..ties.method....first... outcome_H.Hospital_Name
1 4.5                                      1                     ABC
2 4.5                                      2                     CDE
3 5.0                                      3                     EFG
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it myself. I had initialy assigned HA only with one of the three cols(H_A,H_F,PN). Now i clubbed it with hospital_Name and ordered it based on both the attributes.

Thanks,
Pravellika J